# Weibull analysis

Tags: probability, survival, reliability, weibull-distribution

I need to get the maximum likelihood estimate of a two-parameter Weibull distribution. I have tried it on my own but everything tends towards using a Newton-Raphson iterative method which I am not conversant with.

I am trying to show that the maximum likelihood is a better approach than graphical hazard plots using a Weibull distribution and now I need to get the maximum likelihood of a Weibull distribution.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. Why do you need to write your own code? This is a standard problem tackled by any decent statistical software. Conversely, if you do need help writing code, or you are asking for code, either question is off-topic here; in any case people answering that would need to know what software you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use a numerical package OR the graphical method. See this: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section4/apr413.htm and here
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715208002514